# Android how to check my application third party sdk's are suitable for marshmallow

Tags: android, sdk

Please any one help.I am testing my application in marshmallow emulator.App crashes when I am using camera.
    How to check our App third party Sdk's are suitable for marshmallow

// Logcat Errors

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe81c38f0
03-02 00:32:50.804 3199-3199/com.hirewire.hirewire E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.hirewire.hirewire, PID: 3199
                                                                     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/sample.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{cd5f9bb 3199:com.hirewire.hirewire/u0a62} (pid=3199, uid=10062) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2658)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:855)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:907)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:927)
```

Comment: This is not the problem of any 3rd party apis, in Marshmellow all the dangerous permissions need to be asked at run time, when you require access to these dangerous resources and not declared in the manifest file, hence the permission revoked for Camera error, what you can do to get around this is use a lower targetSdkVersion/compileSdkVersion

Comment: Hi Bhargav,Thanks for reply.when I call an API it's work on Lollipop,But In marshmallow showing this Error : E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xf2cbb5a

Comment: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/sample.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{cd5f9bb 3199:com.hirewire.hirewire/u0a62} (pid=3199, uid=10062) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA` this is the problem because of that, this happens `E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xf2cbb5a `